# Does using a "-" in CSS wildcard selectors (officially) mess with matching?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-selectors

Consider these two blocks of code (sorry I couldn't copy and paste, in my frustration I was editing quickly and lost one copy, so I only have the screenshots):

**This one works as expected:**

[image]

**But this one doesn't:**

[image]

Colour me confused. If I go with the second snippet, somehow, even though the browser is detecting these attributes (they show up in the inspector), they aren't being applied. I nearly lost my mind trying to figure out what I did wrong.

Is it because of an issue with the [wildcard selector?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/wildcard-selectors-and-in-css-for-classes/)

Comment: I just need to know I'm not losing my mind, so please, I know this is Stack Exchange, but ***be easy.*** This stressed me out enough on its own.

Comment: No, it shouldn't interfere with matching.

Comment: Please post the actual code so we can reproduce the problem.